# How to update filtered list in swiftui, when the value in the filter is changed?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, filter

Usual caveat of being new to swiftui and apologies is this is a simple question.

I have a view where I have a date picker, as well as two arrows to increase/decrease the day. When this date is update, I am trying to filter a list of 'sessions' from the database which match the currently displayed date.

I have a filteredSessions variable which applies a filter to all 'sessions' from the database. However I do not seem to have that filter refreshed each time the date is changed.

I have the date to be used stored as a "@State" object in the view. I thought this would trigger the view to update whenever that field is changed? However I have run the debugger and found the 'filteredSessions' variable is only called once, and not when the date is changed (either by the picker or the buttons).

Is there something I'm missing here? Do I need a special way to 'bind' this date value to the list because it isn't directly used by the display?

Code below. Thanks

```
import SwiftUI

struct TrainingSessionListView: View {
    
    @StateObject var viewModel = TrainingSessionsViewModel()
    @State private var displayDate: Date = Date.now
    @State private var presentAddSessionSheet = false
    
    private var dateManager = DateManager()
    
    private let oneDay : Double = 86400
    
    private var addButton : some View {
        Button(action: { self.presentAddSessionSheet.toggle() }) {
            Image(systemName: "plus")
        }
    }
    
    private var decreaseDayButton : some View {
        Button(action: { self.decreaseDay() }) {
            Image(systemName: "chevron.left")
        }
    }
    
    private var increaseDayButton : some View {
        Button(action: { self.increaseDay() }) {
            Image(systemName: "chevron.right")
        }
    }
    

    private func sessionListItem(session: TrainingSession) -> some View {
        NavigationLink(destination: TrainingSessionDetailView(session: session)) {
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Text(session.title)
                    .bold()
                Text("\(session.startTime) - \(session.endTime)")
            }
        }
    }
    
    
    private func increaseDay() {
        self.displayDate.addTimeInterval(oneDay)
    }
    
    private func decreaseDay() {
        self.displayDate.addTimeInterval(-oneDay)
    }
    
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                HStack {
                    Spacer()
                    decreaseDayButton
                    Spacer()
                    DatePicker("", selection: $displayDate, displayedComponents: .date)
                        .labelsHidden()
                    Spacer()
                    increaseDayButton
                    Spacer()
                }
                .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 25, leading: 0, bottom: 0, trailing: 0))
                    
                Spacer()
                
                ForEach(filteredSessions) { session in
                    sessionListItem(session: session)
                }
                
                Spacer()
                
            }
            .navigationTitle("Training Sessions")
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
            .navigationBarItems(trailing: addButton)
            .sheet(isPresented: $presentAddSessionSheet) {
                TrainingSessionEditView()
            }
            
        }
    }
    
    var filteredSessions : [TrainingSession] {
        print("filteredSessions called")
        return viewModel.sessions.filter { $0.date == dateManager.dateToStr(date: displayDate) }
    }
}

struct TrainingSessionListView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TrainingSessionListView()
    }
}
```

Comment: You may want to introduce another @State variable where you assign the `filteredSessions`, i.e. create a function returning the filtered set and assign it a corresponding @State variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your responses. I'm not sure what the issue was originally but it seems updating my view to use Firebase's `@FirestoreQuery` to access the collection updates the `var filteredSessions...` much better than what I had before.

New code below seems to be working nicely now.

```
import SwiftUI
import FirebaseFirestoreSwift

struct TrainingSessionListView: View {
    
    @FirestoreQuery(collectionPath: "training_sessions") var sessions : [TrainingSession]
    
    @State private var displayDate: Date = Date.now
    @State private var presentAddSessionSheet = false
    
    
    private var dateManager = DateManager()
    
    private let oneDay : Double = 86400
    
    private var addButton : some View {
        Button(action: { self.presentAddSessionSheet.toggle() }) {
            Image(systemName: "plus")
        }
    }
    
    private var todayButton : some View {
        Button(action: { self.displayDate = Date.now }) {
            Text("Today")
        }
    }
    
    private var decreaseDayButton : some View {
        Button(action: { self.decreaseDay() }) {
            Image(systemName: "chevron.left")
        }
    }
    
    private var increaseDayButton : some View {
        Button(action: { self.increaseDay() }) {
            Image(systemName: "chevron.right")
        }
    }
    

    private func sessionListItem(session: TrainingSession) -> some View {
        NavigationLink(destination: TrainingSessionDetailView(sessionId: session.id!)) {
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Text(session.title)
                    .bold()
                Text("\(session.startTime) - \(session.endTime)")
            }
        }
    }
    
    
    private func increaseDay() {
        self.displayDate.addTimeInterval(oneDay)
    }
    
    private func decreaseDay() {
        self.displayDate.addTimeInterval(-oneDay)
    }
    
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                HStack {
                    Spacer()
                    decreaseDayButton
                    Spacer()
                    DatePicker("", selection: $displayDate, displayedComponents: .date)
                        .labelsHidden()
                    Spacer()
                    increaseDayButton
                    Spacer()
                }
                .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 25, leading: 0, bottom: 10, trailing: 0))
                    
                if filteredSessions.isEmpty {
                    Spacer()
                    Text("No Training Sessions found")
                } else {
                    List {
                        ForEach(filteredSessions) { session in
                            sessionListItem(session: session)
                        }
                    }
                }
                Spacer()
                
            }
            .navigationTitle("Training Sessions")
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
            .navigationBarItems(leading: todayButton, trailing: addButton)
            .sheet(isPresented: $presentAddSessionSheet) {
                TrainingSessionEditView()
            }
        }
    }
    
    var filteredSessions : [TrainingSession] {
        return sessions.filter { $0.date == dateManager.dateToStr(date: displayDate)}
    }
    
}

struct TrainingSessionListView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TrainingSessionListView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches and for your case and for what you described I would take the first one. I only use the second approach if I have more complex filters and tasks

You can directly set the filter on the ForEach this will ensure it gets updated whenever the displayDate changes.

```swift
ForEach(viewModel.sessions.filter { $0.date == dateManager.dateToStr(date: displayDate) }) { session in
    sessionListItem(session: session)
}
```

Or you can like CouchDeveloper said, introduce a new state variable and to trigger a State change you would use the `willSet` extension (doesn't exist in binding but you can create it)

For this second option you could do something like this.

1. Start create the Binding extension for the `didSet` and `willSet`

```swift
extension Binding {
    func didSet(execute: @escaping (Value) ->Void) -> Binding {
        return Binding(
            get: {
                return self.wrappedValue
            },
            set: {
                let snapshot = self.wrappedValue
                self.wrappedValue = $0
                execute(snapshot)
            }
        )
    }
    func willSet(execute: @escaping (Value) ->Void) -> Binding {
        return Binding(
            get: {
                return self.wrappedValue
            },
            set: {
                execute($0)
                self.wrappedValue = $0
            }
        )
    }
}
```

2. Introduce the new state variable

```swift
@State var filteredSessions: [TrainingSession] = []
// removing the other var
```

4. We introduce the function that will update the State var

```swift
func filterSessions(_ filter: Date) {
    filteredSessions = viewModel.sessions.filter { $0.date == dateManager.dateToStr(date: date) }
}
```

5. We update the DatePicker to run the function using the `willSet`

```swift
DatePicker("", selection: $displayDate.willSet { self.filterSessions($0) }, displayedComponents: .date)
```

6. And lastly we add a `onAppear` so we fill the filteredSessions immidiatly (if you want)

```swift
.onAppear { filterSessions(displayDate) } // uses the displayDate that you set as initial value
```

Don't forget in your `increaseDay()` and `decreaseDay()` functions to add the following after the `addTimeInterval`

```swift
self.filterSessions(displayDate)
```

As I said, this second method might be better for more complex filters

Comment: Thanks for your response. I like this paradigm and will most likely use it in future.
For this issue however, using the `@FirestoreQuery` seemed to fix the issues I was having. See below for details. Thanks again.